# How to locate any element based on css style class property value in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to locate an element based on the background-image, see screenshot for reference.

```
<em unselectable="on" class="x-btn-split">
    ...
</em>
```

Style:

```
em.x-btn-split 
{
    background-image: url("/EXT/theme/sfdc/images/button/split_mutton_arrow.png");
}
```

I need to locate the element that have background-image url as "/EXT/theme/sfdc/images/button/split_mutton_arrow.png"

Comment: try this once: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em[@class='x-btn-split']")).getAttribute("background-image");

Answer (score 0):

From what is given, it looks like you can simply check the class here:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("em.x-btn-split")
```

If you insist on checking the `background-image`, you'll have to find all the `em` tags and filter them out checking the `background-image` CSS property in the loop:

```
value_to_find = "/EXT/theme/sfdc/images/button/split_mutton_arrow.png"

try:
    em = next(em for em in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("em.x-btn-split") 
              if em.value_of_css_property("background-image") == value_to_find)
    print("Found!")
    print(em)
except StopIteration:
    print("Not Found!")
```

(Examples in Python)